# How to properly load a native library for sbt tests?

Tags: java, scala, java-native-interface, sbt, classloader

I have a `sbt` project and a `java` class that statically loads a native library and contains the native methods. It looks like this:

```
public class NativeContainer {
  static {
    System.load("/path-to-lib");
  }

  public static native void nativeFunc(int n);
}
```

I also have a `Scala` test that calls the native function like this:

```
class TestJni extends FunSpec { 
  describe("JNI test") {
    NativeContainer.nativeFunc(5);
  }
}
```

When I run the test via `sbt` once, everything works fine. However, at every next run I get:

> [error] Could not run test intrinsics.TestJni:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /path-to-lib already
>   loaded in another classloader

What would be a proper way to load the library to avoid that? Restarting `sbt` works, but I was looking for a more flexible solution.

I don't use any libraries or plugins for glueing `sbt` with `JNI`.

This is the full stack trace:

```
[debug] Running TaskDef(TestJni, org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$1@1d29c60d, false, [SuiteSelector]) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /path-to-lib/libNativeContainer.dylib already loaded in another classloader
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1907)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at NativeContainer.<clinit>(NativeContainer.java:5)
        at TestJni$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(TestJni.scala:16)
        at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.registerNestedBranch(Engine.scala:613)
        at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike$class.describe(FunSpecLike.scala:357)
        at org.scalatest.FunSpec.describe(FunSpec.scala:1626)
        at TestJni.<init>(TestJni.scala:7)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:646)
        at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:76)
        at sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:85)
        at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:197)
        at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:197)
        at sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:185)
        at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:197)
        at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:197)
        at sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
        at sbt.Tests$.sbt$Tests$$processRunnable$1(Tests.scala:239)
        at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:245)
        at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:245)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [error] Could not run test TestJni: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /path-to-lib/libNativeContainer.dylib already loaded in another classloader
```

Comment: Any stack trace? Or is it just the error?

Comment: @JornVernee added the full stack trace.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but if it works once per JVM, you might be able to work around it by setting `fork := true` in sbt, so that a new JVM is forked for each run of tests. see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html

Comment: I guess it looks like what the issue is is that, by default, sbt runs each round of tests in the same JVM but a different ClassLoader, but JNI libraries can only be linked once, not to multiple ClassLoaders. So `fork := true` probably is a good solution, so that your classes are loaded only once per JVM as they probably would be in production scenarios.

Comment: @SteveWaldman that seems like a reasonable solution and it does indeed fix the problem. You might want to add it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: OK, done. I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it looks like what the issue is is that, by default, sbt runs each round of tests in the same JVM but a different ClassLoader, but JNI libraries can only be linked once, not multiple times in multiple ClassLoaders.

sbt has a setting...

```
fork := true
```

...that causes tests to be run in a fresh JVM rather than in sbt's JVM under a new ClassLoader. (See [the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html).) Under this setting, your classes will be loaded only once per JVM (as they probably would be in production scenarios), without illegal attempts to multiply link JNI libraries through different ClassLoaders. This should resolve your issue.